# Getting back the right amount of matches

Tags: php, regex

I have a simple problem, but I've had a hard time find a simple and effective solution to it.

Since I didn't have any success with way I posted what I need to solve the first and the second times, I am going to try it a third time with a more direct question.

After searching the web, I found a solution to dealing with German and French characters, but the underlying problem with the matches I get is the same. 
I simplified the script, so that anyone can try it out.

```
<?php

$lines=array("Ich weiß wirklich nicht, womit er prahlt!: I really 
don't know what he's bragging of!","Worüber hat er gesprochen?: what 
did he talked about?");

foreach($lines as $line){
  preg_match_all('/\b([A-Za-zäöüÖÄÜß\s\.,\'!\?])+([A-Za- 
z\s\.;\'\-!\?]+)/',$line,$lines1,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
  echo 'results = '.$lines1[0][0].'<BR>';
}
?>
```

From preg_match_all I only get two matches:
results = Ich wei� wirklich nicht, womit er prahlt!
results = Wor�ber hat er gesprochen?

But from https://regexr.com/ and https://regex101.com/ I get four matches with the same regular expression.

Ich weiß wirklich nicht, womit er prahlt!
I really don't know what he's bragging of!
Worüber hat er gesprochen?
what did he talked about?

Does anyone know why there's this discrepancy? How can I get four matches with preg_match_all instead of only two?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `- er macht | er machte | er hat gemacht; ` doesn't have a colon.

Comment: Well don't know what you want and you aren't commenting so can't help. The `wei?` issues sounds like you split the unicode character into individual bytes, maybe add `u` modifier.

Comment: @ user3783243 - Thanks for the tip, but  am I suposed to add the   u modifier to the preg_match_all function? I tried to explain what I want again. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is clearer. In your character class the `a-zA-Z` won't expand to the german characters. Replace that with `\p{L}`.

Comment: @user3783243 - Any ideas about the rest? How can I mark your answer as useful without saying that my problem has been solved? Thanks. I do hope someone can shed some light here. :)

Comment: I don't think you can without having a +15 rep. But it's not an answer yet

Comment: Maybe this is good starting place? https://regex101.com/r/UsZgE0/1/ This is using named groups so you will know which rule it matched

Comment: what is yours expected result? what you try to achieve, find all words that contain German characters? sentences? preg_match_all returns in the first element whole matched pattern, while example sites, probably, results form different groups, just add var_dump($lines1) to see how preg_match_all works

Comment: To alleviate some of the complexity with a French / English site I built a couple years ago, I would transform all "special" characters into their HTML entity equivalent, making the matching simpler IMHO, and getting rid of most locale problems.

Comment: @2oppin - The result I expect in this case is 4 matches. In my 1st & 2nd posts I explained I wanted to split each string in two, get rid of the > and : signs and the \s next to them. Then store all German strings in one array and the English ones in another one and then write each array to different files. The strings actually come from a file in a certain format, not from an array. When I've tried this /\b([A-Za-zäöüÖÄÜß\s\.,\'!\?])+/ in the sites I mentioned before, it actually matches both languages, but I doubled it hoping that preg_match_all would match both sides, but it doesn't

Comment: I am unsure if I misunderstand you completely right now, but are you trying to split the strings based on your regex? As far as I can see, you have separated both strings with ":", meaning you could use split(":"); first and then apply your eventual regex on the results. I mean if your headache is based on them not being separated. :-)

Comment: @ Colobri - Yes, you understood it right. As you can see the string begins with **>** sign and a whitespace (which sets it apart from other strings in the file e.g. **- blabla**). In PERL, I surround the parts I want to match in parentheses e.g. **> (Deutsch): (English)** , then by using $1 and $2 respectively I access each match. Then I assign them @deArr=$1 and @enArr=$2. It's done in almost one go, instead of **Replace >**,  **split :**  and add to array. Is there a simple way to do this in PHP? I'm looking for simple and clear code.

Comment: I hope I made myself clear this time. I have 5 types of strings, so first I have to match and group them within IF statements and each IF should do the above stated and then write the contents of every array into a corresponding file. That's why I'm looking for simple code since it's repetitive and I'm not sure howto being new at PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the strings are all separated by the ":" it's really no need to match by the characters. Use your regex to grab the left side and the right side of the ":" regarding of what they are. This works fine on the test-strings you've provided.

```
$lines=array(
   "Ich weiß wirklich nicht, womit er prahlt!: I really don't know what he's bragging of!",
   "Worüber hat er gesprochen?: what did he talked about?"
);

$allItems=array();
$pattern = '/(.*?):\s?(.*?$)/s';
foreach($lines as $line){
   preg_match_all($pattern, $line, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
   array_push($allItems, $result[1][0], $result[2][0]);
}

print_r($allItems);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array ( [0] => Ich weiß wirklich nicht, womit er prahlt! [1] => I really don't know what he's bragging of! [2] => Worüber hat er gesprochen? [3] => what did he talked about? )
```

**EDIT**

For this specific scenario you could omit the use of regex alltogether by instead simply using this, the resulting output would be the same:

```
$lines=array(
   "Ich weiß wirklich nicht, womit er prahlt!: I really don't know what he's bragging of!",
   "Worüber hat er gesprochen?: what did he talked about?"
);

$allItems=array();
foreach($lines as $line){
   $values = explode(": ", $line);
   array_push($allItems, $values[0], $values[1]);
}

print_r($allItems);
```

*I'd prefer to go with this last, but you also said you had other types of strings so it'd probably be best in that case to keep the regex-way if the other string types would just need a pattern-modification to work.*

Comment: I've wouldn't expect that there is only one space after colon, maybe update regex to '/([^:]*):\s*(.*?$)/s',.. same for explode, maybe  array_map('trim', explode(':', $line);

Comment: @Colobri - BEAUTIFUL!!!  That's exactly what I needed from the beginning. Simple, elegant, and effective!! Now I need to learn how to say my question has been answer, and also thank 2oppin for that beautiful yet simple RegEx that he provided. It's very useful. Next I'm going to add part of my final code in case anyone would be interested. Colibri - You mentioned that you'd prefer to use the explode() instead, what's better?

Comment: @Bert_AT - Glad I could help you! :D - To mark an answer as "the" answer, you click the checkmark beneath the rank-buttons. :)

In this case, I would go with 'explode' if I knew that all strings would be in this format. I don't know the impact on performance, but I find it more 'readable' than the regex.

Regex can be used to do a lot of really advanced stuff, and it's super-fun - but it feels a bit overkill for this specific scenario. :-)